# Python - Date Diff On An Anchor Date

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find the date diff between my anchor date and the other dates grouping by ID.

Input

```
ID  Date        Anchor Date
123 1/5/2018    N
123 4/10/2018   N
123 5/8/2018    Y
123 10/12/2018  N
234 1/4/2018    N
234 1/4/2018    N
234 1/4/2018    Y
456 5/6/2018    N
456 5/6/2018    N
456 5/10/2018   N
456 6/1/2018    Y
567 3/2/2018    N
567 3/2/2018    N
567 3/2/2018    Y
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  Date        Anchor Date Diff
123 1/5/2018    N           -123         
123 4/10/2018   N           -28
123 5/8/2018    Y            0
123 10/12/2018  N            157
234 1/4/2018    N            0
234 1/4/2018    N            0
234 1/4/2018    Y            0
456 5/6/2018    N           -26
456 5/6/2018    N           -26
456 5/10/2018   N           -22
456 6/1/2018    Y            0
567 3/2/2018    N            0
567 3/2/2018    N            0
567 3/2/2018    Y            0
```

Code Attempt

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv()
df['Date'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['diff'] = df['diff'].fillna(0)
```

The error I am receiving is "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index."
And secondly, I am not sure how to incorporate the *Anchor Date* column to ensure that is used for time zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert `Date` into `datetime` type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

After that, can extract the index of the `Anchor Date` with `idxmax`, then use `loc` to extract the actual dates:

```
idx = df['Anchor Date'].eq('Y').groupby(df['ID']).transform('idxmax')
df['Diff'] = (df['Date'] - df.loc[idx, 'Date'].values) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Another way is to extract those Date with boolean indexing, and map:

```
anchor_dates = df.loc[df['Anchor Date']=='Y', ['ID','Date']].set_index('ID')['Date']

df['Diff'] = (df['Date'] - anchor_dates)/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Output:

```
     ID       Date Anchor Date   Diff
0   123 2018-01-05           N -123.0
1   123 2018-04-10           N  -28.0
2   123 2018-05-08           Y    0.0
3   123 2018-10-12           N  157.0
4   234 2018-01-04           N    0.0
5   234 2018-01-04           N    0.0
6   234 2018-01-04           Y    0.0
7   456 2018-05-06           N  -26.0
8   456 2018-05-06           N  -26.0
9   456 2018-05-10           N  -22.0
10  456 2018-06-01           Y    0.0
11  567 2018-03-02           N    0.0
12  567 2018-03-02           N    0.0
13  567 2018-03-02           Y    0.0
```

Comment: How should I address the error of "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"?